# Glossaries on the bar of \overline command

Tags: hyperref, symbols, glossaries, glossaries-extra

I would like to make a glossary of a text where sometimes operations are described.
One of this is the "overline" operation.

In the text, I would like to write:

```latex
\gls{Overline}[u]
```

such that only the bar created by the `\overline` command is linked to the glossary, and not the argument under it (here `u`).

Picture bellow shows the kind of result I want (links in red color):

[image: Wanted result]

The following code is largely inspired by [Symbols with optional parameter in glossaries with \newglossary](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/316777/symbols-with-optional-parameter-in-glossaries-with-newglossary) issue:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hidelinks, colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\usepackage[abbreviations]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries
\glsnoexpandfields

\newcommand*{\glsdefaultarg}{i}
\newcommand*{\glsarg}{\glsdefaultarg}

\newglossaryentry{Overline}{
    category=arg,% requires an argument
    name=\ensuremath{\overline{\glsdefaultarg}},
    text=\ensuremath{\overline{\glsarg}},
    description={Overline description}
}
% modify the entry's format

\preto\glsentryfmt{%
  \glsifcategory{\glslabel}{arg}% if category set to "arg"
  {%
    \ifdefempty\glsinsert
    {\let\glsarg\glsdefaultarg}%
    {%
      \let\glsarg\glsinsert
      \let\glsinsert\empty
    }%
  }%
  {}%
}

\begin{document}

\(\gls{Overline}\)

\phantom{}

\(\gls{Overline}[a]\)

\phantom{}

\(\gls{Overline}[(u, v)]\)

\phantom{}

\(\gls{Overline}[f]\)

\phantom{}

\(\gls{Overline}\)

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

It outputs this:

[image: LaTeX output]

As you can see, both the bar produced by `\overline` and the text under it are linked to the glossary (in red thanks to `hyperref` package).

Note that the printed glossary is correct.

The key idea is perhaps to create a macro that simulates `\overline` result (see with tikz here: [a bolder \overline](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164503/a-bolder-overline)), and customise the glossary format in the text. But I don't really know how to do this.

Thank you for reading me,
Have a nice day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to simulate `\overline` behaviour and make the line clickable and coloured.

While it is quite ugly, it works, so I tag the question answered.
But I would be really enjoyed if someone has a cleaner way to do this.

The code (note that I created a simpler MWE without glossaries `arg` category).
Furthermore, here the colour of the glossary text entry is not the same as the one of other link (page number in Glossary section).

```latex
% ============================================================================ %
%                                    CONFIG                                    %
% ============================================================================ %
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hidelinks, colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\usepackage[abbreviations]{glossaries-extra}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc} % because of 'let' in tikzpicture env.

% ============================================================================ %
%                                   HYPERREF                                   %
% ============================================================================ %
\newcommand{\customglshrefcol}{blue} % Cleaner bc we will reuse this command

% ============================================================================ %
%                                  GLOSSARIES                                  %
% ============================================================================ %
\makeglossaries%

% ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- %
%                                  Link Color                                  %
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- %
\renewcommand*{\glstextformat}[1]{\textcolor{\customglshrefcol}{#1}}

% ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- %
%                                     Entry                                    %
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- %
\newcommand{\overbardefault}{\ensuremath{\,\cdot\,}}
\newglossaryentry{overbar}{
    name=\ensuremath{\overline{\overbardefault}},% for the printglossaries
    text={},% because \Overline command will replace \gls behaviour
    description={Overline description}
}

% ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- %
%                               Simulate Overline                              %
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- %
\newcommand\Overline[2][0.5pt]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(a.base)]
        %
        % The text under the line
        %
        \node[inner xsep=0pt,inner ysep=1.5pt] (a) {$#2$};
        %
        % Write link on the overline
        %
        \path let
        \p1=(a.north west),
        \p2=(a.north east),
        \n1={veclen(\x2-\x1,\y2-\y1)} in
        node[outer sep=0pt,inner xsep=0pt,align=left,anchor=west,minimum width=\n1,minimum height=1ex]
        at (a.north west) (link) {% \glshyperlink[<text>]{<label>}
                \glshyperlink[%
                    \gls{overbar}\hphantom{\hspace*{\n1}}% we use \gls to add page number in Glossary section
                ]{overbar}%
            };
        %
        % Draw overline
        %
        \draw[line width= #1, color=\customglshrefcol] (a.north west) -- (a.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

% ============================================================================ %
%                                     BODY                                     %
% ============================================================================ %
\begin{document}

\(\Overline{\overbardefault} \quad \overline{\overbardefault}\)

\phantom{}

\(\Overline{a} \quad \overline{a}\)

\phantom{}

\(\Overline{(u, v)} \quad \overline{(u, v)}\)

\phantom{}

\(\Overline{f} \quad \overline{f}\)

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

It outputs:

[image]

The code is highly inspired by https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/526333/232319

Comment: to subscript/power the overlined text with the new `\Overline` command, it is necessary to call `\text` before.
e.g. `L_{\text{\Overline{f}}}`

Comment: See my solution over at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/668364/76043